# The ServicePointManager does not support proxies of * scheme

Tags: .net, web-services, proxy

I've encountered two different variations of this:

"The ServicePointManager does not support proxies of proxy scheme"
"The ServicePointManager does not support proxies of HTTPS scheme"

I get this error when a client attempts to connect to our webservices through a proxy. I've encountered this problem with a few clients using proxies, though I have no idea what's causing it. The proxy is set with System.Net.WebProxy and default credentials.

Using .Net 1.1, with Microsoft.Web.Services2.

Any one know what could be causing this?

Comment: This also occurs when restoring packages from NuGet from an https url, particularily in Visual Studio 2019. It can also occur when attempting to restore a service dependency while publishing an app in VS 2019.  In this case the error can be vague and result in a generic rollback exception. Why restoring NuGet packages in this way doesn't support HTTPS I don't know.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

OK. Making sure the proxy address is prefixed with "http://" Seems to have fixed this in all the cases I've come across so far.

Comment: I feel stupid for not adding http:// in the first place. It is in the docs! I just copied it the internet explorer proxy settings and it didn't work. Thank for the answer.

Comment: Also you can see adding of `http://`in `System.Net.WebProxy.CreateProxyUri` private method

Answer (score 3):

I just run Fiddler with setting Automatically Authenticate on/checked. It worked for me.

Comment: Had Fiddler running in the background --- which triggered this issue for me. your comment solved my issue (by closing it anyways).  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This was an interesting error that I had to hunt down.  When specifying a proxy server in .NET like this: WebProxy("https://someproxyserver") you will get this error.  You will get this error for whatever scheme that you enter before the "://" characters.  For example if you use this: WebProxy("somescheme://someproxyserver") Then you will get the error message: The ServicePointManager does not support proxies of somescheme scheme.  The only scheme that is recognized by this class is http.

You will also get this error if you set something like this in your .config file: proxyAddress="myproxy.somewhere.local:8080"
You MUST list the scheme like this:   proxyAddress="http://myproxy.somewhere.local:8080"

Discussion - Most organizations do not have an HTTPS Proxy server.  This is not necessary because if SSL communication is required, this communication is between the endpoint server and the Client, not the Proxy and the client.  This does not mean that SSL communication is in anyway not secure through an http Proxy.  The SSL traffic is encrypted and tunneled through the Proxy just fine and this is no less secure than going directly to the SSL based target  (as long as you trust your proxy).  It is only the initial connection to the Proxy that is not over SSL.

The above solution from following link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jpsanders/the-servicepointmanager-does-not-support-proxies-of-https-scheme-net-1-1-sp1