# Consuming a Wcf service in Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8

I have already seen this link for connecting local web service in windows phone 8 emulator.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

But this is not enough, i am trying to consume a remote wcf service in my windows phone 8 application; but every time i am getting a 407 proxy authentication required error.

Service is working fine but I am not able to consume the service; in windows store apps i can consume this service without any problems, but in windows phone 8 im not able to consume properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395677/error-407-proxy-authentication-required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to add it in your web.conf

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
</system.net>
```

Or this ?

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy usesystemdefault="False"/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```